# Rails scope with combined attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, scope, rails-activerecord

I am trying to create a scope where checkin_time (DateTime) is added with duration (Int) in hours which is greater than or equal to Time.now

So something like this

```
scope :current, -> { where('checkin_time + duration.hours >= ?', Time.now) }
```

However, the string `'checkin_time + duration.hours >= ?'` above is not valid. How can I achieve something that will give me the correct result?

Comment: @muistooshort I am using psql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing to do with PostgreSQL is to convert your `duration` to an `interval` and add that `interval` to your timestamp. Something like this:

```
where("checkin_time + (duration || 'hours')::interval >= ?", Time.now)
```

or even:

```
where("checkin_time + (duration || 'hours')::interval >= now()")
```

The `duration || 'hours'` builds a string like `'6hours'` and then the `::interval` casts that string to an `interval` which can be added to a timestamp.